# Error in Dynamically setting the Fragment

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments, fragment

I am trying to set up a fragment dynamically. I need to do it in the `FragmentActivity`. Here is what I have tried.

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Fragment frag = new InputFragment();

        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();   
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

}

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >



    </FrameLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

**InputFragment.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class InputFragment extends Fragment {

    private Button submit;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.input, container,false);


        submit = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.input_submit_button);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new SubmitButtonAction());


        return view;

    }

    private class SubmitButtonAction implements OnClickListener
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Fragment frag = new OutputFragment();

            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();   
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        }

    }

}
```

There is an compile error. Here it is.

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from android.app.FragmentTransaction to android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction
```

This error is coming from `FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();` of `MainActivity.java`

I tried fixes suggested by Eclipse, but it gave me nothing. When I fix the error using exlipse suggestions, it gives another error. When I fix it using eclipse suggestions (clicking on eclipse suggestions) it comes back to the previous error.

What am I doing here wromg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use fragments below Android sdk vrsion 3.0,then use getSupportFragmentManager() method available in support 4 support lib.
(Make sure to put supportv4 lib in your lib folder and add in your project build path)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can use transition with the support library. A few suggestions:

1. Remove this line `ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);`
2. Or if you're targeting API 14 or higher you may instead `extend Activity` and use `getFragmentManager()`